# Can't complete npm install when directing Docker to local NPM packages

Tags: docker, dockerfile, npm-install

I haven’t been able to find an answer to this question anywhere, so I’m hoping someone here might have run into a similar issue.

I’m trying to containerize a NodeJS application, but run into this error during `RUN npm install`:

> npm ERR! Could not install from "packages/example-package" as it does
>   not contain a package.json file

The package in question is listed as a local dependency in my app’s package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@example-name/example-package": "file:../example-package"   },
```

There are no issues running `npm install` outside of docker with these local file paths.

I’ve tried copying the packages package.json file into the container, via the Dockerfile, like so:

```
COPY ./packages/example-package/package.json ./packages/example-package
```

The resulting error is:

> npm ERR! Could not install "packages/example-packages" as it is not a
>   directory and is not a file with a name ending in .tgz, .tar.gz or
>   .tar

I’m at a loss as to where to go from here! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You end up with a file called `./packages/example-package` with the contents of the `package.json` rather than a directory.

You can confirm this by temporarily adding a `cat` of the file/dir to your `Dockerfile`

```
RUN cat ./packages/example-package
```

Use a `/` on the end of the destination path to make it a directory or specify the full path to the file.

```
COPY ./packages/example-package/package.json ./packages/example-package/

COPY ./packages/example-package/package.json ./packages/example-package/package.json
```